# Dangling commit is not in reflog and won't purge by git gc

Tags: git, garbage-collection, git-log, git-revert, git-reflog

I got a dangling commit that is not in the reflog (or I use it wrong) and won't go away with `git gc`. Here is what I mean:

```
% git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (5425/5425), done.
dangling commit e681384da8babd4524f545bd880dfc602d271e45
dangling blob 77835dc1395f57d359d81f2c240d02a6ff1e9a69
...

% git reflog | grep e681

% git gc
Counting objects: 5425, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1585/1585), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5425/5425), done.
Total 5425 (delta 2086), reused 5425 (delta 2086)

% git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (5425/5425), done.
dangling commit e681384da8babd4524f545bd880dfc602d271e45
dangling blob 77835dc1395f57d359d81f2c240d02a6ff1e9a69
...
```

Also there is nothing that would explain it for me:

```
% git config gc.reflogExpireUnreachable

% git config gc.pruneExpire
```

I see that the commit is a revert and has a history back to the early days:

```
% git log e681384da8babd4524f545bd880dfc602d271e45 --oneline | tail -n 2
b50e1de base file structure
9a4b3af first commit
```

But why won't this commit go away?

I am eager to know this because it's so good at making no sense to me :D

Comment: Did you try `git gc --prune=all`? (To answer your question - gc has a default "hold" period of two weeks before it purges loose objects. Source: man page)

Comment: And there it goes. So easy. Sorry, I thought to read in the logs that it's from Oct 27. But now it's gone. Didn't read that `man` well enough I think.